# Get a group of column values from pandas dataframe on condition

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe:

```
item    B    val
1    qw      0
2    ss    0.9
3    ds   -0.8
4    sd    0.4 
5    dd    0.9
6    ll    0.4
7    wr    0.3
8    rt    -0.4
9    qq    0.2
10   ee    0.6
```

In the values column the first row is `0`, and then followed by a positive number `0.9`

I want to find the group of items where the consecutive values are positive.

For eg:

```
items in groups = [1,2] ## consecutive positive val [4,5,6,7] and [9,10]
```

Final output I am looking forward is

```
[ [1,2] , [4,5,6,7] , [9,10] ]
```

Is this possible without iterating the `dataframe` in `for` loop?

Comment: I don't see any integers in your data. So all your values are up to one decimal point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
m = df['val'].ge(0)
df.index = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()
L = df[m.values].groupby(level=0)['item'].apply(list).tolist()
print (L)
[[1, 2], [4, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10]]
```

**Explanation**:

1. First compare by [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ge.html) for greater and equal `(>=)`
2. Get consecutive values to index by compare by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`) of [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)
3. Filter only positiove values and `0`s by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)
4. [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and create `Series of list`s, last convert it to `nested list`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
mask=df.val.lt(0)
df.item[~mask].groupby(mask.cumsum()[~mask]).apply(list).tolist()
Out[236]: [[1, 2], [4, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10]]
```